# EPID issue for AddFixedPriceItem

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-net-sdk

I'm trying to use AddFixedPriceItem to add listings to my eBay store.  I'm including ProductListingDetails as follows:

```
{
    IncludeeBayProductDetails = false,
    IncludeeBayProductDetailsSpecified = true,
    UseFirstProduct = true,
    UseFirstProductSpecified = true,
    ProductReferenceID = info.eBayProductId,
}
```

I'm using the eBay.Service NuGet package to make my call.  However, when the item gets listed, it doesn't include the EPID or any reference to the product.  What am I missing?  I've left IncludeeBayProductDetails as false, as I don't want to overwrite my own title/description/images/etc.  What else do I need to do in order to get eBay to pick up this added information?